# Audiotoolbox crashes – Programming error or OS unable to process fast enough?

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, core-audio, audiotoolbox

Through Fabric I get tons of crashes in my shipped app, all related to the Audiotoolbox. Here's a selection:

**Crash 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS**

*LayerState::FindConnectionWithSource*

```
Crashed: AURemoteIO::IOThread
0  AudioToolbox                   0x18447d030 LayerState::FindConnectionWithSource(unsigned int, unsigned int) + 64
1  AudioToolbox                   0x184491404 SamplerNote::Configure(InstrumentState*) + 516
2  AudioToolbox                   0x184492874 non-virtual thunk to SamplerNote::Attack(MusicDeviceNoteParams const&) + 52
3  AudioToolbox                   0x1844afc54 SynthGroupElement::NoteOn(SynthNote*, SynthPartElement*, unsigned int, unsigned int, MusicDeviceNoteParams const&) + 76
```

**Crash 2: EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS**

*VoiceZone::GetLayerID*

```
Crashed: AURemoteIO::IOThread
0  AudioToolbox                   0x185d4a1d0 VoiceZone::GetLayerID() const + 12
1  AudioToolbox                   0x185d36f78 SamplerNote::NotifyVoiceFinished(VoiceZone const&) + 40
2  AudioToolbox                   0x185d4a2c0 VoiceZone::Process(unsigned long long, AudioBufferList**, unsigned int, unsigned int) + 232
3  AudioToolbox                   0x185d36e44 non-virtual thunk to SamplerNote::Render(unsigned long long, unsigned int, AudioBufferList**, unsigned int) + 168
```

**Crash 3: EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS**

*Connection::Connection*

```
Crashed: AURemoteIO::IOThread
0  AudioToolbox                   0x27203802 Connection::Connection(ConnectionState*) + 109
1  AudioToolbox                   0x272477ab VoiceZone::AddConnection(ConnectionState*) + 114
2  AudioToolbox                   0x272477ab VoiceZone::AddConnection(ConnectionState*) + 114
3  AudioToolbox                   0x27245473 VoiceZone::BuildConnections() + 46
```

**Crash 4: EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS**

*VoiceZone::VoiceZone*

```
Crashed: AURemoteIO::IOThread
0  AudioToolbox                   0x18455bc34 VoiceZone::VoiceZone(SamplerNote*, ZoneState*, float, float, unsigned int) + 584
1  AudioToolbox                   0x18455b96c VoiceZone::NewVoiceZone(SamplerNote*, ZoneState*, float, float, unsigned int) + 80
2  AudioToolbox                   0x1845498e0 SamplerNote::Configure(InstrumentState*) + 1760
3  AudioToolbox                   0x18454a874 non-virtual thunk to SamplerNote::Attack(MusicDeviceNoteParams const&) + 52
```

**Crash 5: EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS**

*LayerState::GetMatchingZones*

```
Crashed: AURemoteIO::IOThread
0  AudioToolbox                   0x2407413e LayerState::GetMatchingZones(ZoneSelector const&, std::__1::vector<ZoneState*, STLAllocator<ZoneState*> >&) const + 49
1  AudioToolbox                   0x24088105 SamplerNote::Configure(InstrumentState*) + 1120
2  AudioToolbox                   0x24088105 SamplerNote::Configure(InstrumentState*) + 1120
3  AudioToolbox                   0x240890c9 non-virtual thunk to SamplerNote::Attack(MusicDeviceNoteParams const&) + 36
```

**Crash 6: EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS**

*SamplerNote::Configure*

```
Crashed: AURemoteIO::IOThread
0  AudioToolbox                   0x184ed5618 SamplerNote::Configure(InstrumentState*) + 1048
1  AudioToolbox                   0x184ed6874 non-virtual thunk to SamplerNote::Attack(MusicDeviceNoteParams const&) + 52
2  AudioToolbox                   0x184ef3c54 SynthGroupElement::NoteOn(SynthNote*, SynthPartElement*, unsigned int, unsigned int, MusicDeviceNoteParams const&) + 76
3  AudioToolbox                   0x184ed32fc SamplerElement::StartNote(SynthPartElement*, unsigned int, unsigned int, MusicDeviceNoteParams const&) + 408
```

**Crash 7: SIGABRT ABORT**

```
Crashed: AURemoteIO::IOThread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x38a94c84 __pthread_kill + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x38b38733 pthread_kill + 62
2  libsystem_c.dylib              0x38a2cf21 abort + 108
3  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x38ac60bd free_list_checksum_botch + 362
```

**Crash 8: EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS**

*VoiceFilter::VoiceFilter*

```
Crashed: AURemoteIO::IOThread
0  AudioToolbox                   0x23463090 VoiceFilter::VoiceFilter(FilterState*, unsigned long, float) + 103
1  AudioToolbox                   0x233b9e99 VoiceZone::VoiceZone(SamplerNote*, ZoneState*, float, float, unsigned long) + 552
2  AudioToolbox                   0x233b9e99 VoiceZone::VoiceZone(SamplerNote*, ZoneState*, float, float, unsigned long) + 552
3  AudioToolbox                   0x233b9beb VoiceZone::NewVoiceZone(SamplerNote*, ZoneState*, float, float, unsigned long) + 122
```

Are these errors due to programming mistakes made by me, or could they occur because the OS wasn't able to process the buffer block fast enough? (Which in turn would mean I need to work on the performance.)

Bonus points if you can tell me what the individual runtime errors mean.

Comment: AFAIK, in a pull-model the real-time thread produces audio buffers on input, consumes buffers on output. If _your program_ does not process the buffers fast enough you may get silence or drop-outs. However, if you make OS responsible for processing the buffers by making _blocking_ calls, Obj-C _allocs_ and _releases_ on the real-time thread, strange things can happen. What do you mean by "individual runtime errors"?

Comment: Those errors look more like buffer overrun memory corruption or a memory management bug in your code.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, and thanks for pointing me in the right direction. After some more reading I also think that this is probably due to a buffer overrun memory corruption. I'm revising the render callback now. With individual runtime errors I meant what exactly "VoiceFilter::VoiceFilter" and all those things do. But I guess that's just random internal functions that crash because of the memory problems.